# HOOK_module_theme_suggestions_node_alter suggestion twig not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I implemented a HOOK_module_theme_suggestions_node_alter to add a custom twig template. Now below is my code

```
function gf_theme_module_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    $suggestions[] = 'node--products-template--simple';
  
}
```

Now it does appear in the inspector but the page does not use the custom twig file I added eventhough the file exist. Any idea?

Below are the screenshot

[image]

[image]

I already cleared my cache but still no luck. It's still loading the node.html.twig eventhough the `node--products-template--simple.html.twig` exist. The file exist in the same folder as the `node.html.twig` file

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or the cause of the issue, but the hook name is _HOOK_theme_suggestions_node_alter_ (not _HOOK_module_theme_suggestions_node_alter_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use underscores instead of hyphens in suggestions:

```php
$suggestions[] = 'node__products_template__simple';
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me hours of headaches! ;)